# Liberty Packaged Server Deployments

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have an application that was pushed to the Liberty runtime via the packaged server deployment method and I understand that some of the default features provided by Liberty will change in one of the upcoming [buildpack updates](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/07/22/liberty-buildpack-updates-java-ee-7/).  Will this change in default features provided adversely affect my packaged server deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're deploying/restaging your application in a manner other than a packaged server or a server directory, then the change in the default feature set **might affect** your application.  This is due to the changes in spec levels in the new default feature sets.  However, if you used the "packaged server" or the server directory method for deploying your app then you will **not be affected**.  This is because the features you put in your server.xml will still get picked up due to the fact that the buildpack will provide Java 6 & 7 features.

If you need more information about the new default features added to the buildpack, how to make your app resilient to the changes, and even how to "preview" the new buildpack for testing purposes, see the link below:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/09/08/upcoming-liberty-for-java-buildpack-changes/